# Intra-disk redundancy options

Tags: hard-drive, redundancy

I have enough single disk systems deployed in harsh-environments that https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_rot is a problem.  Disks get corrupted regularly.

My question is, if I'm willing to sacrifice a significant portion of my disk's space and performance, are there any nifty solutions out there that could help with reliability?

Another search has revealed the other people may be thinking about this too: [Evaluation of Applied Intra-disk Redundancy Schemes to Improve Single Disk Reliability](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6005374)
However I don't have access to the report.

Throwing more hardware at the problem is not an option, I'm stuck with what I have already.

What options are there for achieving additional redundancy/reliability when using single disk setups?